# Angular issue not pointing to src folder even with new project creation

Tags: angular, typescript, path, routes, angular8

Man! What's wrong with Angular? or Node? I can't figure out why I can no longer create simple js and css files and call them inside the "index.html" file! When I call them from "index.html" file, the autocompletion works fine and points to their correct paths.. But when I hover on their path holding "ctrl" button to open them, Visual Studio Code can't find them!! Wait, whaaaat? You just suggested me the correct path! 
When I try to build the project, I find the output dist in a hell of disorder: some images are in the root folder, and some others are in "/assets/img" folder.. When I deploy the output folder to the server, it can't even point to the basic js and css files!

I even tried to create a new blank project, and a file called "app.js" in the same level as "index.html", I just have put a "console.log" instruction inside the "app.js" and then call it in the "index.html" with:

`<script src="app.js"></script>`

and

`<script src="./app.js"></script>`

but none of them seems to work! it searches for the file in a one level up from the src folder, not INSIDE the src folder! It usually works fine, I don't know what happened with Angular..

By the way, I tried this on 2 different PCs, with 2 different Angular versions (8 and 7), and 2 different code editors, I even uninstalled and re-installed the latest version of Node.js and cleaned the cache, and whatever new project I create on both PCs, I face the same problem!

Here is a sample project path on github:
[Angular issue](https://github.com/fereshenteti/angular-issue)

Any Ideas about what it could be? Thank you!

Comment: Please check any chance of adding base tag will update the source path of JavaScript files

Comment: It's the editor problem seems so

Comment: @JayakumarThangavel do you mean <base href="/"> ?

Comment: @HitechHitesh I have tried Atom editor as well.. nothing changes..

Comment: Yes. Did you included that base tag in that file and is that any luck to resolve it. If you can share the steps which you followed to create the project and deploy project then it will be easy identify the solution.

Comment: @JayakumarThangavel yes it exists by default.. I will be updating my post in a few minutes to include the project link in github

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got stuck in this problem somethimes to, and change the

```
<base href="/">  to  <base href="./"> or even <base href="../">
```

resolve the issue, also change when establish the call and change it to ../../ at the beggining of the calls, the intellisense dont recognizes the path, but stills works for me.
well this solution sometime help me, let me kwon what happens